# Complex Regex Pattern Validation

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate a complex regex, but I'm not too sure how to begin with my approach. I am changing different things using a regex tester, but it's a bit complicated. I am using Angular's Validator.pattern to verify this text input.

The string I am testing validation on is:

`1;D;00:00|04:59|5%;05:00|8:59|35%;09:00|14:59|35%;15:00|23:59|25%,2;D;00:00|04:59|5%;05:00|14:59|30%;15:00|23:59|65%`

The way it is broken down is it is comma delimited between objects and each object has different parts that are delimited by semicolons

**First part:** `1`, this can be any positive integer, my best guess would be something like `^\d+$`?

**Second Part:** `D`, this can be either A or D, something like this: `[AD]`?

**Third Part:** `00:00|04:59|5%;05:00|8:59|35%;09:00|14:59|35%;15:00|23:59|25%`, this part would be the most complicated. It would take in 2 time ranges and then a percent between 0-100%, each part separated by a `|` delimiter. The ranges should ideally add up to 100% and the time ranges to not overlap, but that validation can be done in a separate service, I just want the format correct as of right now. So as long as the input would be 2 time ranges and a percentage, it would be accepted.

https://regex101.com/r/hPXPE8/1

I created a regex tester to test things out if that makes it easier.

Comment: You might use repeating groups matching the the digit, AD time and percentage sign https://regex101.com/r/b2Svvo/1 and between the repeating items match either a comma, semicolon or end of the string `(?:[;,]|$)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the pattern to match the beginning `\d+;[AD];`.

Use `(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]` to match the time part and use `\|` to match a pipe.

Use `(?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])%` to match the 0-100 percentage part and a character class `[;,]` to match either `;` or `,`

Combining those to a larger pattern with repeated parts, you might use:

```
^\d+;[AD];(?:(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\|(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\|(?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])%[;,])*(?:\d+;[AD];(?:(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\|(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\|(?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])%(?:[;,]|$))*)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hhw64T/1)

In global, the parts look like

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+;[AD];` Match start pattern
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\|` Match time pattern 2x times
  - `(?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])%[;,]` Match percentage 0-100
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d+;[AD];` Match start pattern
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\|` Match time pattern 2x times
    - `(?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])%` Match percentage 0-100
    - `(?:[;,]|$)` Match either `;`, `,` or end of string
  - `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of string